# Can't find MySQL Workbench 6.1 32-bit setup for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit, but I can't find MySQL Workbench 6.1 32-bit setup for Ubuntu. If you have it, then send me a link.

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu 14.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

This will install MySQL Workbench version 6.0.8 and also install MySQL Workbench -- architecture independent data (mysql-workbench-data) as a dependency. MySQL Workbench is available in Ubuntu 14.04 in two different architectures, one for 32-bit and the other one for 64-bit. This is close enough to the requested version, MySQL Workbench 6.1, that you should seriously consider installing MySQL Workbench 6.0.8 from the Ubuntu repositories instead of MySQL Workbench 6.1.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 the default version from the default Ubuntu repositories is  MySQL Workbench version 6.3.6.